# Intersections: Generator

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

**Problem**

Given a set $\Omega$.

Define the generator:
$$\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{P}\Omega:\quad\delta\mathcal{A}:=\{A\cap A':A,A'\in\mathcal{A}\}$$

Then one obtains:
$$\mathcal{\delta}^\infty\mathcal{A}:={\bigcup}_{n=0}^\infty\delta^n\mathcal{A}:\quad\delta(\delta^\infty\mathcal{A})=\delta^\infty\mathcal{A}$$

How can I check this?

**Attempt**

In general only:
$$\mathcal{A}_n\in\mathcal{P}\Omega:\quad\delta\left({\bigcup}_{n=0}^\infty\mathcal{A}_n\right)\supseteq{\bigcup}_{n=0}^\infty\delta\mathcal{A}_n$$

As counterexample:
$$A\neq A':\quad\mathcal{A}:=\{A\}\quad\mathcal{A}':=\{A'\}$$
Then one obtains:
$$\delta(\mathcal{A}\cup\mathcal{A}')=\{A,A\cap A',A'\}\supsetneq\{A,A'\}=\delta\mathcal{A}\cup\delta\mathcal{A}'$$
So for any union!

Comment: HINT: Try to prove that for $A \in \delta^n( \mathcal{A})$ and $A' \in \delta^m( \mathcal{A})$ you have $A \cap A' \in \delta^{\max (n,m)}( \mathcal{A})$.

Comment: @Crostul: Ah right that solves the problem. Thanks alot!! :)

Comment: @Crostul: I think you really need: $A\cap A'\in\delta^{m+n}\mathcal{A}$

Comment: @Crostul: Is it ok for you if I post in answer in your name?